# oAuth blank page

Tags: templating, plugins

I have installed the [oAuth](https://dukt.net/oauth/) and [Social Poster](https://github.com/engram-design/SocialPoster) plugins. Created OAuth 2 app via Twitter API Manager. Went to Keys and Access Token and copied Consumer API Key and API Secret and pasted into Client Id and Client Secret (OAuth). When I went to Social Poster plugin / Accounts / Twitter and hit the Connect button. It redirects  `/sample.com.au/index.php/admin/actions/socialPoster/accounts/connect?handle=twitter` to `sample.com.au/index.php/admin/actions/oauth/connect?provider=twitter`. It appear to be blank and no warning.

I followed the guidelines from two plugin's homegpage and no success getting it to work.

I am not sure if my other plugins are interfering with the process or because I moved Craft outside of domain for security measure.

Could anyone advice me how to setup the plugin properly so I can start sending entries to Twitter.

Comment: If you enable devMode do you get an error instead of a blank page?

Comment: Hi, I have turn on devMode and now I can see the error. Fatal error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in /home/zeze3574/public_html/craft/plugins/oauth/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 78. What does that error mean?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you're getting:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in /home/.../public_html/craft/plugins/oauth/vendor/guzzle‌​http/guzzle/src/Hand‌​ler/CurlFactory.php on line 78
```

I'd guess that your cURL installation goes have [curl_reset](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-reset.php) available to it, for whatever reason.  Maybe your host has it in your php.ini file's [disable_functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) setting.

Comment: Thank Brad, I checked my web host and yes it was not activate which I have request to be activate. Now I am recieving a new error. Received HTTP status code [401] with message "{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}" when getting temporary credentials. Does that mean the id and sercet code is inncorrect? I basically copied and paste Owner ID and Consumer Secret from Twitter App

Comment: Yeah, not familiar with the plugins, but the error message sounds like it's some credential problem.